# ElementName binding for items in a custom ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I'm looking to create a custom ItemsControl where the nested items use ElementName binding to another control. For the standard ItemsControl this works fine and the binding works as expected

```
<ItemsControl>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</ItemsControl>
<TextBox x:Name="test"/>
```

However, as soon as I come to use a custom control inheriting from ItemsControl as follows

```
<!-- CustomItemsControl.xaml -->
<ItemsControl x:Class="MyControl.CustomItemsControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"/>

<!-- CustomItemsControl.xaml.cs -->
namespace MyControl
{
    public partial class CustomItemsControl 
    {
        public CustomItemsControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

<!-- Window.xaml -->
<local:CustomItemsControl>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</local:CustomItemsControl>
<TextBox x:Name="test"/>
```

Then the ElementName binding is no longer working. Has anyone else seen this issue and know how to resolve it?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posting the code for your CustomItemsControl would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the xaml file for your CustomControl. You just need to create a class in your local namespace like this which inherits from ItemsControl-

```
public class CustomItemsControl : ItemsControl
    {

    }
```

And it should work as desired..!!

Comment: Reason for the XAML is that I'm wanting to have a specific layout of the template that is hidden from the users of this control. However, the removal of the InitializeComponent() works great. Do you know why removing that fixes it?

Comment: InitializeComponent() registers the `NameScope` for the given custom control and overriding `NameScope` looses `ElementName`'s relevance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx